# TCP proxy - mutex

Tags: c++, tcp, proxy, mutex

i want to write a simple TCP proxy in C++ for the University. The proxy works with two threads one reads from source port and writes to the destination port and the other thread does the same in the other direction. The aim is to read and manipulate the packets in the future. If i use the mutex to lock the port for read and write on the same port i got package loss. Can you help me to locate the problem because i tried it a long time now?

```
    thread1 = 0;
    thread2 = 0;



    //Client

    struct sockaddr_in address;
    int size;

    if ((create_socket=socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) > 0)
        printf ("Socket wurde angelegt\n");
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_port = htons (PORT);
    inet_aton (IP, &address.sin_addr);
    if (connect ( create_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &address, sizeof (address)) == 0)
        printf ("Verbindung mit dem Server (%s) hergestellt\n", inet_ntoa (address.sin_addr));


    //Server

    socklen_t addrlen;
    struct sockaddr_in address2;
    const int y = 1;
    if ((create_socket2=socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) > 0)
        printf ("Socket wurde angelegt\n");
    setsockopt( create_socket2, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &y, sizeof(int));
    address2.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address2.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    address2.sin_port = htons (PORT2);
    if (bind ( create_socket2, (struct sockaddr *) &address2, sizeof (address2)) != 0) {
        printf( "Der Port ist nicht frei – belegt!\n");
    }
    listen (create_socket2, 5);
    addrlen = sizeof (struct sockaddr_in);
    new_socket2 = accept ( create_socket2, (struct sockaddr *) &address2, &addrlen );
    if (new_socket2 > 0)
        printf ("Ein Client (%s) ist verbunden ...\n", inet_ntoa (address2.sin_addr));



    thread apm(apm_gcs);
    thread gcs(gcs_apm);

    apm.join();
    gcs.join();

}


inline void apm_gcs()
{


    while (STOP==FALSE)
    {       
        {
            lock_guard<mutex> lock(tcp60Mutex);
            res = read(create_socket, buffer2, sizeof(buffer2));   // returns after 5 chars have been input 
        }

        {
            lock_guard<mutex> lock(tcp65Mutex);
            write(new_socket2, buffer2, res);
        }
    }
}





inline void gcs_apm()
{

    while (STOP==FALSE)
    { 
        {
            lock_guard<mutex> lock(tcp65Mutex);
            res2 = read(new_socket2, buffer, sizeof(buffer));   // returns after 5 chars have been input 
        }

        {
            lock_guard<mutex> lock(tcp60Mutex);
            write(create_socket, buffer, res2);

        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help.
Greets
Tobi

Comment: Aren't individual reads/writes guaranteed to be atomic (making the mutexes overkill anyway)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things to improve.

First of all: It's not clear what exactly you want to protect. I would understand if you would use one mutex to protect one buffer, and the other mutex for the other buffer, so each buffer will always be accessed by only one thread. However, that does not happen - both threads can read+write the same buffer at the same time. Instead, each mutex protects a socket against read+write at the same time, which is pointless because sockets can handle that perfectly. You can read+write on the same socket at the same time. sockets are used to do that for more than 30 years now.

Once that is changed and your mutexes protect buffers, you will run into blocking again, though less often. You will experience that a thread tries to read or write data while none is available, or the socket connection is full (which happens if you try to quickly write large amounts of data) and it takes time to transfer the data.

This can be solved then by select() or maybe by poll(). Thus the way to go is:

Each thread uses select() or poll() to find out if it can read or write data. Only if it can, it locks the mutex for the buffer, then read or write data (which won't block after select() or poll() made that sure) and then releases the mutex.

Comment: In fact, `select` would eliminate the need for two threads per connection in the first place.

Comment: That's true. Just, some programmers find it simpler to use several threads anyway, and it he prefers that, it doesn't matter to use 2 threads. Using just one thread, however, would have the advantage that mutexes won't be needed.

Comment: A lot of threads to handle sockets may not scale well with a large number of connections.